# Assigning Null to NSMutableData or checking if its empty

Tags: swift, macos, nsdata

I need to return `null` or an empty value to identify an error condition. Since `NSMutableData` is not assignable to  **NULL** in the following method, I'm just initialising it using the `init()` method.

Now how I check if the data is empty or is it possible to return null?

```
func generatedata(input:URL)->NSMutableData?
{
    if(errorcondition)
    {
        return NSMutableData.init()
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can't you return `nil`? Why do you need `NULL`? Any reason why you use `NSMutableData` instead of `Data`? You can use `isEmpty`, but since you are retuning an optional, I don't see the why.

Comment: I agree with Larme, what language do you want to write this in? You seem to be unable to make your mind whether it's Swift or Objective-C. :) This is the sort of code an Objective-C programmer might write on their first day trying to use Swift (how well I remember)... Almost everything about it isn't actually Swift. The parentheses around the condition, gag me with a spoon. You've got everything but the semicolons.

Comment: Return `nil` on error. That's what nil is for. (not`NULL`, `nil`.)

Comment: I will return `nil` as most of you suggested :)

Answer (score 2):

The *swifty* way is to throw an error and return non-optional `Data` on success

```
func generatedata(input: URL) throws -> Data
{
   if errorcondition { throw anError }  

   return ...
}
```

`anError` represents a custom error conforming to `Error`

Or return empty `Data()` which can be checked with `isEmpty`

But never use reference type `NS(Mutable)Data` in Swift